# How address of a function will pass to the std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I was debugging a multithreaded application that is using `std::thread` to run a function. I reach to the following code when debugging.

```
extern "C" uintptr_t __cdecl _beginthreadex(
    void*                    const security_descriptor,
    unsigned int             const stack_size,
    _beginthreadex_proc_type const procedure,
    void*                    const context,
    unsigned int             const creation_flags,
    unsigned int*            const thread_id_result
    )
{
    _VALIDATE_RETURN(procedure != nullptr, EINVAL, 0);

    unique_thread_parameter parameter(create_thread_parameter(procedure, context));
    if (!parameter)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD thread_id;
    HANDLE const thread_handle = CreateThread(
        reinterpret_cast<LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES>(security_descriptor),
        stack_size,
        thread_start<_beginthreadex_proc_type, true>,
        parameter.get(),
        creation_flags,
        &thread_id);

    if (!thread_handle)
    {
        __acrt_errno_map_os_error(GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    if (thread_id_result)
    {
        *thread_id_result = thread_id;
    }

    // If we successfully created the thread, the thread now owns its parameter:
    parameter.detach();

    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(thread_handle);
}
```

But I couldn't understand how address of the function passed to the `CreateThread` API. Why is it using `thread_start<_beginthreadex_proc_type, true>`, and how the address of a function will calculate by this statement in order to run by threads?

Comment: The address of the function and it's parameter are stored in `parameter`.

Comment: *"that is using `std::thread`"*. Whereas I see threading code, I don't see `std::thread`. Do you want to modernize that code to use `std::thread`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Looks like OP is looking at an implementation of std::thread

Comment: from where you take this src code ? by this code thread begin execute from common entry point `thread_start<_beginthreadex_proc_type, true>`. this function take user defined entry point from `parameter` and call it

Comment: @RbMm This is MSVC library code.

Comment: @PaulSanders may be. but i can not found where :) anyway sense of code understandable - user defined entry point (`procedure`) saved (`create_thread_parameter(procedure, context)`) in some structure and it address (`parameter.get()`) passed to common entry point `thread_start<_beginthreadex_proc_type, true>`

Comment: @RbMm https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=vs-2019

Comment: @PaulSanders - and so what ? how this is related to concrete src ?

Comment: @RbMm The source of the CRT is supplied with the 'Windows kits'  used in Visual Studio, IIRC, but you have to hunt them down before the debugger will step through them because they are located in a different directory to the one they were in when they were compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code shown ([`_beginthreadex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=vs-2019) function) is part of VC++ CRT (can be found in, e.g.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\startup\thread.cpp`).

An instance of `unique_thread_parameter` is a structure that holds the thread `procedure` pointer, the `context` argument, and thread and module `HANDLE`s:

```
// corecrt_internal.h
typedef struct __acrt_thread_parameter
{
    // The thread procedure and context argument
    void*   _procedure;
    void*   _context;

    // The handle for the newly created thread.  This is initialized only from
    // _beginthread (not _beginthreadex).  When a thread created via _beginthread
    // exits, it frees this handle.
    HANDLE _thread_handle;

    // The handle for the module in which the user's thread procedure is defined.
    // This may be null if the handle could not be obtained.  This handle enables
    // us to bump the reference count of the user's module, to ensure that the
    // module will not be unloaded while the thread is executing.  When the thread
    // exits, it frees this handle.
    HMODULE _module_handle;

    // This flag is true if RoInitialized was called on the thread to initialize
    // it into the MTA.
    bool    _initialized_apartment;
} __acrt_thread_parameter;

// thread.cpp
using unique_thread_parameter = __crt_unique_heap_ptr<
    __acrt_thread_parameter,
    thread_parameter_free_policy>;
```

`create_thread_parameter` creates such an instance:

```
static __acrt_thread_parameter* __cdecl create_thread_parameter(
    void* const procedure,
    void* const context
    ) throw()
{
    unique_thread_parameter parameter(_calloc_crt_t(__acrt_thread_parameter, 1).detach());
    if (!parameter)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    parameter.get()->_procedure = procedure;
    parameter.get()->_context   = context;

    // Attempt to bump the reference count of the module in which the user's
    // thread procedure is defined, to ensure that the module will stay loaded
    // as long as the thread is executing.  We will release this HMDOULE when
    // the thread procedure returns or _endthreadex is called.
    GetModuleHandleExW(
        GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS,
        reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(procedure),
        &parameter.get()->_module_handle);

    return parameter.detach();
}
```

`thread_start` is a template function that invokes the thread procedure:

```
template <typename ThreadProcedure>
static unsigned long WINAPI thread_start(void* const parameter) throw()
{
    if (!parameter)
    {
        ExitThread(GetLastError());
    }

    __acrt_thread_parameter* const context = static_cast<__acrt_thread_parameter*>(parameter);

    __acrt_getptd()->_beginthread_context = context;

    if (__acrt_get_begin_thread_init_policy() == begin_thread_init_policy_ro_initialize)
    {
        context->_initialized_apartment = __acrt_RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED) == S_OK;
    }

    __try
    {
        ThreadProcedure const procedure = reinterpret_cast<ThreadProcedure>(context->_procedure);

        _endthreadex(invoke_thread_procedure(procedure, context->_context));
    }
    __except (_seh_filter_exe(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()))
    {
        // Execution should never reach here:
        _exit(GetExceptionCode());
    }

    // This return statement will never be reached.  All execution paths result
    // in the thread or process exiting.
    return 0;
}
```

It essentially calls `invoke_thread_procedure`, which just invokes `procedure`, passing in `context`:

```
static __forceinline unsigned int invoke_thread_procedure(
    _beginthreadex_proc_type const procedure,
    void*                    const context
    ) throw()
{
    return procedure(context);
}
```

The code around the calls does some bookkeeping to keep the CRT consistent, for example it
automatically cleans up the thread upon exit (`_endthreadex`).