CreateThread() will increase the reference count of the DLL that contains the thread entry point! When did Microsoft introduce this?
CreateThread() will increase the reference count of the DLL that contains the thread entry point, and decrease the reference count when the thread exits. When did Microsoft introduce this?
Also, why does FreeLibraryAndExitThread() only subtract 1 from the reference count, though it contains two operations that decrease the reference count -- FreeLibrary() and ExitThread() FreeLibraryAndExitThread() should subtract 2 from the reference count.
UPDATE: I'm using the C++ std::thread and _beginthreadex() to create the thread, and using the WinDbg command !dlls to view the reference count of the DLL.

"CreateThread() will increase the reference count of the DLL" - Are you sure? Because this question and this blog suggest otherwise. Where are you getting your information from? How are you monitoring the reference count?

It seems unlikely they would have forgotten to decrement the reference count when a thread exits if they had indeed made it increment it when it begins, so I would suggest you have possibly misanalyzed the situation.

The reference count for a module is incremented each time the module is loaded by a call to LoadLibrary instead of CreateThread. The reference count is decremented each time the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function is called for the module. A thread that must unload the DLL in which it is executing and then terminate itself should call FreeLibraryAndExitThread instead of calling FreeLibrary and ExitThread separately. Otherwise, a race condition can occur.

@Jeaninez-MSFT "Otherwise, a race condition can occur." - There is no race condition. Everything is completely deterministic and predictable. If you call FreeLibrary() from a thread and the call results in the module backing the code executing getting unloaded, it returns into unmapped memory. Predictably so, which is distinctly different from a race condition characterized by non-determinism.

@RemyLebeau Sorry for the unclear description, I've used the c++ std::thread and _beginthreadex to create thread and use WinDbg command !dlls to view the reference count of dll. Seems they will call SHCreateThread as @Anders said below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63501887/21201111 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/65523418/21201111 are relative questions

Please don't change the question to a different question once an answer has been submitted.

@HeacheBear you would have to look at your compiler's implementation code to verify, but it is very unlikely that it would be using SHCreateThread()

CreateThread does not bump the refcount, but _beginthreadex does. The refcount is then dropped when you call _endthread or _endthreadex. My psychic powers tell me that you use ExitThread instead of _endthreadex`. The documentation has a big box that says " do not call the Win32 ExitThread API so that you don't prevent the run-time system from reclaiming allocated resources. _endthread and _endthreadex reclaim allocated thread resources and then call ExitThread."

Yes, I overlooked this point. And thanks, it is the answer what I want

CreateThread does not increment the module reference count of the entry point. However, SHCreateThread with the CTF_FREELIBANDEXIT flag will increment the module reference count and MSDN says that this flag is implicit on Vista and later. SHCreateThread calls CreateThread internally.
